# Combining a 3D array with a single test score

Tags: python, arrays, conv-neural-network

I am looking for a function (if possible) that is able to combine a 3D MRI image array with a corresponding test score of a patient and then feed it into a CNN network

For example, if I were to have the following:

```
# each 3D array is an MRI image converted into array format
image_array = [[3D array 1], [3D array 2], [3D array 3]]
test_score = [100, 50, 75] # in seconds
```

how would I be able to to make sure that each test score will be "connected" to the correct image array (3D array 1 has a score of 100 seconds, 3D array 2 has a score of 50 seconds, 3D array 3 has a score of 75 seconds) and be able to pass this into a CNN network (in other words, make sure that the array is still 3 dimensions)?

The output of the CNN network should be a numerical number representing a predicted test score of an MRI image. Ex: the model predicts that this image array has a test score of 62 seconds.

Here is the code for creating my images and labels:

```
# Where the file is located
path = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline'
folder = os.listdir(path)

target_size = (96, 96, 96)

# creating x - converting images to array
mri = []
for i in range(len(folder)):
    files = os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder[i])
    for j in range(len(files)):
        image = np.array(nib.load(path + '\\' + folder[i] + '\\' + files[j]).get_fdata())
        image = np.resize(image, target_size)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=3)
        image /= 255.
        mri.append(image)


# creating y - one hot encoder
excel_file = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline_label.xlsx'
excel_read = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
excel_array = np.array(excel_read['Label'])
label = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(excel_array)
label = label.reshape(len(label), 1)
onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(label)


# Splitting image train/test
x = np.asarray(mri)
y = np.asarray(onehot)
#x_split, x_test, y_split, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, stratify=y)
#x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_split, y_split, test_size=.25, stratify=y_split)
#print(x_train.shape, x_val.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_val.shape, y_test.shape)
```

Here is the code for creating my test scores:

```
mri_path = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\get_skullstrip'
category = os.listdir(mri_path)

subject_id = []
for i in range(len(category)):
    ppmi_files = os.listdir(mri_path + '\\' + category[i])
    for j in range(len(ppmi_files)):
        num = ppmi_files[j][5:9]
        subject_id.append(num)
        
test_path = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\Trail_Making_A_and_B.csv'

scores = []
csv_read = pd.read_csv(test_path)
patno = np.array(csv_read['PATNO'])
tmtasec = np.array(csv_read['TMTASEC'])
for i in range(len(subject_id)):
    for j in range(len(patno)):
        split = len(subject_id) - len(files)
        if subject_id[i] == str(patno[j]):
            if math.isnan(tmtasec[j]) != True:
                scores.append(tmtasec[j])
                break
            else:
                if i < split:
                    scores.append(0.)
                    break
                elif i >= split:
                    scores.append(200.)
                    break
        elif subject_id[i] not in str(patno):
            if i < split:
                scores.append(0.)
            elif i >= split:
                scores.append(200.)
            break
```

Note: some subjects did not have a test score so I had to replace those with 0 and 200

Note2: all the arrays are in order (that means mri[0], onehot[0], and scores[0] are from the same person)

**How do I go about combining the 3D MRI image array with the corresponding test scores? Should I train_test_split before or after I combine them? Will this affect how I can feed this into the CNN network?**

Any help is appreciated and thank you!

Comment: As long as you have everything in order, it will work good. For 3D array, you can use Conv3D layers then Dense layers. For train_test_split, you should do it before, just make sure x.shape[0] and y.shape[0] are equal.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question, I am trying to combine x1 (which are the mri images) and x2 (which are the scores) so that I can train_test_split them later with y (the labels) and THEN feed these into the CNN network. I am having trouble on how to combine x1 and x2 into single array that can be used for the next steps